# ROS Answers SE migration: Unary stack

Tags: ros, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have successfully wrapped an external library into ROS framework following instructions in the tutorial. However, I have used a stack and a package to acheive this. I would like to switch to using a unary stack instead. I am not sure about how to create a unary stack. I do not use CMakeLists.txt in my package for wrapping the external library and as such CMakeLists.txt files in stack and package are not a problem. However, what should be done about the Makefile(s) in stack and package in order to create a unary stack from current stack-package. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12124/unary-stack/) by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2011-11-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to be a unary stack, just take your package and add a stack.xml file as well -- i.e. use the CMakeLists.txt and Makefile from the package.  The only thing you need to add is version information to the stack.xml or CMakeLists.txt, which is described in REP 109:

http://ros.org/reps/rep-0109.html#stack-version

This works as of Electric.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-11-28**:
Not necessarily in general. In your case of wrapping a single external library it probably makes sense. That way the package can be released by itself.

**Comment by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on 2011-11-28**:
Thanks a lot! In general, is the use of unary stacks recommended?